# How to hide from browser's display the output of echo in php when the form is submitted? I used jquery validate for validation

Tags: php, jquery-validate, echo

I want to hide the output of 'echo' on top of my page whenever I register a new user. Also, I'm using jQuery-validate remote in my script. I also tried `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` to hide this, but it doesn't insert all the data into database. Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

```
if(isset($_POST['uname'])){
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uname']);
    $query = "SELECT * from tbl_users where Username = '$uname'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "false";
    }
    else {
        echo "true";
    }   
}
//on submit
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
    $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uname']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
    $pwd = md5($pwd);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE Username='$uname'";
    $checkRows = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkRows) > 0){
        echo "You are already registered";
    }
    else {
        $query = "INSERT into tbl_users(Firstname,Lastname,Email,Username,Password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email','$uname','$pwd')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        echo "REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY";
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}
```

Here is my script. Please help me.

```
$('#registration-form').validate({  
rules: {
  uname: {
    minlength: 6,
    required: true,
    alphanumeric:true,
    remote: {
      url: 'includes/registration.php',
      type: "post"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have all PHP logic in a single file? If you move the cited part to a separate file (say, validate.php) does it fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, I put it in a separate file, but still im getting the output echo on top of my page.

Comment: so remove the `echo` lines.

Comment: If I remove all those echo lines. My validation will not work.

Comment: You say "doesn't insert all the data into database", but I don't see any INSERT statements. What *exactly* is your question? Please be precise.

Comment: check my post, i already added the code with insert query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to add a parameter in my script then pass it on my php file.

```
$('#registration-form').validate({  
  rules: {
    uname: {
    minlength: 6,
    required: true,
    alphanumeric:true,
    remote: {
      url: 'includes/registration.php',
      type: "post",
      data: {
        'username_check': 1,
        uname: function (){
          return $('#registerUsername').val();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my updated php file. I called the parameter I created in my script.

```
if(isset($_POST['username_check'])){
  $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uname']);
  $query = "SELECT * from tbl_users where Username = '$uname'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "false";
  }
  else {
    echo "true";
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your explanation is that you have a page generated by a php file. That page also gets called from JavaScript/AJAX. When called via AJAX, it needs the true/false output so that the validation code in JavaScript can work. However, when it is just generating a page, then the output should not be there. What you are saying is that the true/false output is conditional. Therefore, the PHP code has to have a way to know if it is being called from JavaScript or not.

If I have misunderstood you are asking, please update your question.

One way to do that is to pass another parameter when it is called from AJAX.

```
$isAjax = $_GET['isAjax'] ?? false;
if(isset($_POST['uname'])){
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uname']);
    $query = "SELECT * from tbl_users where Username = '$uname'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        if ( $isAjax ) echo "false";
    }
    else {
        if ( $isAjax ) echo "true";
    }   
}
```

Then, when you call it from JavaScript, tell it you want the output.

```
$('#registration-form').validate({  
rules: {
  uname: {
    minlength: 6,
    required: true,
    alphanumeric:true,
    remote: {
      url: 'includes/registration.php?isAjax=1',
      type: "post"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I now get the logic !